# Run script on login

Tags: scripting, login

I have a Minecraft server running on OS Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 with systemd.

I need to create a user called shutdown which, on login (even from `ssh`) should:

- Run script `shutdownAll`
- Log out from session

The `shutdownAll` script should be the following (or equivalent):

```
systemctl stop minecraft
shutdown +5 "SERVER SHUTDOWN IN 5 MINUTES"
```

Any ideas to do it?
***EDIT:*** I've thought about using a command as shell, but how do I execute two commands?

Comment: Did you try putting those commands in the `shutdown` user's shell's start-up file (like, in `~/.bashrc`)?

Comment: Does the user have the ability to run `systemctl` with sudoer rights so that it can actually stop the service?

Comment: @they @Nasir Riley Didn't try using `~/.bashrc`, but I had made a script to be run manually. It was in the sudoer file, but didn't recognize `systemctl`. Used a `Cmd_Alias` with permission for just `/sbin/shutdown` and `/bin/systemctl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this.
I've created a new script (`/usr/local/bin/management/shutdownAll`), containing

```
sudo systemctl stop minecraft
sudo shutdown +5 "SERVER SHUTDOWN IN 5 MINUTES"
```

And made it executable with `chmod +x shutdownAll`.
Then edited `visudoer` file adding

```
shutdown ALL = ALL
```

And called `usermod -s /usr/blocal/bin/management/shutdownAll`.
On login, the password is asked twice (but it's ok), once for login and once for sudo, then the server is stopped, poweroff scheduled 5 minutes later and session is closed.